# Find a file path

Tags: c#, path

I'm creating a program that controls if words in a textbox are present in a text file.
The question is: Is there a way to find the path of that file without depending on the computer you're on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use an absolute value for the path - it'll always try to resolve it relative to where your application is.

So if you put the file in the same folder as your application, it'll find it.

Otherwise, if you want your user to locate the file for you, you could use an `OpenFileDialog`[Example here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/openfiledialog)

Another option is to use one of the 'known' paths (such as My Documents). You can do this using [Environment.GetFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx)

But all of these depend on what you're trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative paths. For example, if your path is "file.txt" and save the file, it will be saved next to your exe. Same thing for opening.